# Как перевести дату из формата yyyy-mm-dd в общепринятый вид?

Tags: java

Есть дата вида "2015-05-15". Как из неё сделать дату вида "15 мая 2015"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

С помощью `SimpleDateFormat` (чтобы "мая" получилось по-русски, нужна, соответственно, локаль). Пример:

```
 String oldDateString = "2015-05-15";
 SimpleDateFormat oldDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());
 SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy", Locale.getDefault());

 Date date = oldDateFormat.parse(oldDateString);
 String result = newDateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: 2015-06-08 он преобразует в 6 января 2015

Comment: @Radzhab, обновил ответ

Answer (score 9):

В дополнение к сказанному выше, предлагаю воспользоваться новыми классами из пакета java.time, который появился в Java 8, а не пользоваться давно уже устаревшим java.util.Date

```
String dateString = "2015-05-15";
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"));
System.out.println(date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMMM yyyy", new Locale("ru"))));
```