# Преобразование String в Date format

Tags: java

Имеется `String`:

```
      String date = "11.03.2015";
```

и интервал дат:

```
      String startDate = "01.03.2015";  
      String endDate= "30.03.2015";
```

Как проверить попадает ли `String date` в заданный интервал.

Пробую так:

```
       boolean isWithinRange(Date testDate)
            {
             return testDate.after(startDate) &&                              
                    testDate.before(endDate);
            }
```

Но при этом выдается ошибка

> The method getTime() is undefined for the type String.

Как тогда преобразовать `String` в `Date`?

Или можно как то по другому сравнивать?

Comment: `String startDate = 01.03.2015;  String startDate = 30.03.2015;` - как такое может быть? Наверное, это опечатка. Либо должны быть разные названия, либо надо убрать `String` перед вторым присвоением `startDate`.

Comment: И где кавычки? Должно быть так: `String date = "11.03.2015"`.

Comment: причем тут `C#`?

Comment: ну обычно кто C# знает тот обычно знает яву

Comment: это кто вам сказал?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/423989/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-yyyy-mm-dd-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4

Answer (score 3):

Для преобразования `String` в `Date` воспользуйтесь классом [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = format.parse("11.03.2015");
```